# devise session time_out

Tags: devise, session-timeout

I need to make timeout_in as dynamic value like below,But here self is not a instance of User model. can any one have idea how I can use that condition .

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :token_authenticatable,  :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable , :omniauthable,:timeout_in =>  (self.email.nil? ? 111.minutes : 112.minutes)

Answer (score 2):

This feature is on Devise master and should be released on a new Devise version soon. You can point your Gemfile to Devise git repository and start using it right now.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-timeout_in-value-dynamically
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/1462

Comment: I've released Devise version 1.5.2 with this feature. Check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do that this way, since you are on a class scope.

To do what you want, define a method called timeout_in method that implements this logic. Because it has [this method](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/timeoutable.rb#L39) Devise tries to load timeout_in from an instance method, and after this it tries to get it from the class method.

EDIT: removed the monkey patch solution added a better one.

EDIT2: Improving the answer.

Comment: So isn't any way to achieve my goal(set timeout_in value according to user type.)?

Comment: Yes there is a way. 

Maybe this was not clear on my reply, so I improved the answer.

Comment: "after this it tries to get it from the class method." please pardon it.
Could you please give me line of code what you asking. As I done by different way without using device timeout_in :
http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/7400

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo,But its not getting help for me...:(

Comment: Neelesh, I will try to find a solution.

Comment: Turns out that it is not possible to put it on the user instance now. I will reopen your issue on Devise issues.